# Push notification service like parse?

Tags: ios, push-notification

In Parse I know you can send push notification from one device to another, but since it is shutting down soon I have looked at a lot of push notification services. But I could not find one service which allows you to push to other users. i.e. Firebase, you send out notifications from the computer. Basically I need a service when a function is called in the code it goes to certain people automatically. Any service suggestions?

Comment: You working on IOS or Android or both and what language for web ?

Comment: I am working with iOS only right now. I am open to any language for web

Comment: Try PHP as back end and APNS for push notification

Answer (score 0):

If you have an own server, connect it with FCM. Then create an API using PHP to receive message and forward it to another device. You may implement a system to store the FCM token of the devices in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Create you own app server that will send a push notification to either APNS/GCM according to the user device type and device token id
2. Use push provider. I recommend you to use **OneSignal** because its 100% free, support in all devices and have an SDK to any client/server side technology so if you will use OneSignal you will not need any server in-between your app and the push server.

this is the onesignal home page: https://onesignal.com/
and this is the SDK docs page: https://documentation.onesignal.com/

BTW! if you want to can also continue to use parse services because they release their service as an open source which called [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) 
so you can take and deploy parse-server to any cloud platform that run NodeJS and then you can continue to work as usual

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that but I thought push notification does not transfer over in the migration

Comment: it is. You just need to configure it on your own. you have all the details in here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push but if you are only use parse for push then go with onesignal